# UPS unable to power the 1U server

Tags: electrical-power, ups, apc-smart-ups

1U rack server: http://ark.intel.com/products/67786/Intel-Server-System-R1304GL4DS9

Power backup: http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BR1000G-IN

When I try starting the server only on backup power then the whole device beeps and does not start. In case the server is already running then it continues to run on backup power when main power supply goes down. The server has 460W gold efficient PSU and UPS is rated at 600W/ 1000VA which I believe can handle the load of the server. 6A is the output rating per socket for this UPS.

Does server require a lot of power when started and cannot start on backup power ?

Technical specifications on the website say UPS is 84% efficient on full load. Does this mean maximum load server can handle is 600 x 0.84 = 504W and/ or 1000 x 0.84 = 840VA ?

If I increase the UPS capacity to 850W/1500VA then will it be possible to start the server on backup power ? How can I decide the minimum UPS capacity needed ?

Comment: Why are you trying to *boot* the server while on battery power? Yes, the system requires more power at initial boot versus steady running power.

Comment: @ewwhite I am trying to construct a small 4 1U server rack that can be powered in remote area completely on backup power inside a vehicle. So I started testing with UPS I have here at home (listed above). How can I calculate the initial power required by the servers ?

Comment: If ups cannot provide electricity for server, then it must show some errors (load is to high). Are battery in UPS is in good condition?

Comment: @Guntis Yes, if I put the running server on backup then UPS shows pretty good 70 mins of backup!!! problem occurs only while starting the server

Comment: If UPS cannot handle load, it must beep or show some warnings or turn itself off. Also i never seen UPS that can lasts 70 mins! Can you test server with another UPS ?

Answer (score 5):

The UPS you have is said to be ["Cold-start" capable](http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BR1000G-IN&tab=features).  Try these instructions:

> Press and hold the power button until it starts beeping.

If that does not work try this:

> To cold start a Smart-UPS:
>
> 1. Turn OFF and Unplug the UPS from the wall
> 2. Press and HOLD the power button (Test) on the front of the UPS until you hear a long beep
> 3. During the long beep, let go of the TEST button. If you waited too long and the beep stopped, you’ll have to do it again
> 4. If you let go during the long beep, the UPS should start, go through the self test and run off battery power. The unit will beep to
>      let you know that it’s running on batteries
> 5. If you’r testing to see if the wall outlet is working, you can plug the UPS back in to the wall socket, if there is acceptable power, the
>      UPS will switch to normal operation

[SOURCE](http://excessups.com/blog/how-to-cold-start-smartups/)

Comment: +1 This is technically correct. Buy there are clearly more concerns about what the OP is doing.

Comment: @xeon Thanks for replying but I think this solution is more applicable when the UPS itself is not starting. In my case the UPS could not take up the load required to start the server. UPS did not face any starting problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be helpful to get more detail about what you're doing. [The answer that references cold-starting your UPS](https://serverfault.com/a/563996/13325) is correct in that it tells you how to get your UPS running without utility power.

But it sounds like you want to run your servers from inside a vehicle.

- Do you know how much battery runtime you need?
- Will you need networking?
- Have you considered laptop computers?
- Have you considered DC inverters to run off of vehicle power?
- Have you considered [purpose-built vehicle computers](http://www.nexcom.com/Products/mobile-computing-solutions/in-vehicle-pc) that can run off of the vehicle's DC power?
- What is the application for this? It's an odd request.

Comment: The application is to train unskilled people in rural areas on some of the common graphics editing applications (maybe other applications too in future) that may improve their job prospects. Right now my thought is to host thin clients on which the trainees can practice their lessons. I would be happy if I can keep the rack running for 30-45 mins during the lesson each day. Networking between the servers and thin clients is required but not as internet if you mean so. Those purpose built computers are new to me but I think they cost $200+ or maybe more!

Comment: @i01000001 Have you considered a generator instead? Maybe (too)  expensive...

Comment: @Henk Way too expensive! I did look into it earlier but including all sort of possible expenditures related to generators I think it can be used only when one expects good amount of revenues.